Prevent running a Gitlab job at some time
I have a GitLab CI/CD pipeline that consists of several jobs, deploy_dev -> deploy_staging -> deploy_live.
Is there a way to configure deploy_live such that it won't run at some time? even when deploy_staging is a success? like starting from Friday 1PM until Monday 8AM?
